# Passing an array as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters

So I'm doing a programming assignment and I've ran into an issue, when every I attempt to pass the arrays to the header file, I receive an error while compiling, I'm not too clear as how to do this and would much appreciate so assistance in passing these arrays.

Here is the Header file "sorting.h"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int cost = 0;

void bubble(int Ar[],int N)
{
  cost=0;
  int swaps = 1;
  while(swaps)
  {
    swaps=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
    {
      if(Ar[i]>Ar[i++])
      {
        swap(Ar[i],Ar[i++]);
        swaps = 1;
        cost += 6;
      }
      cost++;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    cout<<Ar[i]<<endl;
  }
  cout<<cost<<endl;
}

void shellSort(int Ar[], int N)
{
  cost=0;
  int swaps = 1;
  int gap = N/2;
  while(gap>0)
  {
    while(swaps)
    {
      swaps = 0;
      for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
      {
        if(Ar[i]>Ar[i+gap])
        {
          swap(Ar[i],Ar[i+gap]);
          swaps = 1;
          cost+=6;
        }
        cost++;
      }
    }
    gap=gap/2;
  }
  for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
  {
    cout<<Ar[i]<<endl;
  }
  cout<<cost<<endl;
}


void quickSort(int Ar[],int left, int right, int N)
{
  cost = 0;
  int i=left,j=right,tmp;
  int pivot = Ar[(left+right)/2];
  /*partition*/
  while(i<=j)
  {
    while(Ar[i]<pivot)i++;
    while(Ar[j]>pivot)j--;
    if(i<=j)
    {
      tmp=Ar[i];
      Ar[i]=Ar[j];
      Ar[j]=tmp;
      i++;
      j--;
      cost +=6;
    }
    cost+=1;
  }
  /* recursion*/
  if(left<j)quickSort(Ar,left,j,N);
  if(i<right)quickSort(Ar,i,right,N);
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    cout<<Ar[i]<<endl;
  }
  cout<<cost<<endl;
}

/*#if _INCLUDE_LEVEL__<1
int main()
{

}
#endif*/
```

and here is the main file "sorting2.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "sorting.h"

using namespace std;

//void bubble();
//void shellSort();
//void quickSort();

int main()
{
  int N = 20;
  int Ar[N];
  int Ar2[N];

  for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
  {
    Ar[i] = Ar2[i] = rand()%100;
  }

  bubble(Ar[],N);

  for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
  {
    Ar[i] = Ar2[i];
  }

  shellSort(Ar[],N);

  for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
  {
    Ar[i] = Ar2[i];
  }

  quickSort(Ar[],0,19,N);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lose the `[]` in the argument lists of you function invokes in `main()`

Comment: Unrelated, Props that you're actually doing a bonified bubble sort with swap-checking (you'd be amazed how many don't), but your bubble sort sorts to the very end of the array repeatedly. `while (swaps && N--) { swaps=0; for (i=0; i<N; ++i) { do you stuff } }`. You get the idea. no sense is comparing data you don't have to, especially since you're benching and all. And the `i++` in your inner loop should be `i+1`

Comment: As your implementation is in header, your function should be `inline` to avoid multiple definition. (But it seems better to split declaration and definition in header/cpp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 bubble(Ar[],N);
```

to

```
 bubble(Ar, N);
```

(and in other similar places as well)

There are also other problems in your code:

1. Variable-length arrays are not part of C++ standard:

   ```
   int Ar[N];
   int Ar2[N];
   ```

   You should change `int N = 20;` to `const int N = 20;`
2. This line produces undefined behavior because the order of evaluation of operator arguments is unspecified:

   ```
   if(Ar[i]>Ar[i++])
   ```

Comment: About 2.: i++ should definitively be i+1.  There and in the next occurrence in the code.